# MySQL wrap join condition with another condition?

Tags: mysql, join

I've made a query that works as needed when there is at least 1 row in the url_status table where **u.urlid = us.urls** however it won't work if this isn't true. What could I do to overcome this?

```
SELECT u.*, COUNT(*) AS historySize
FROM host_urls u, url_status us
WHERE u.publicationid = 1
AND us.urlid = u.urlid
GROUP BY u.urlid
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use an outer join, specifically a left join, which will return at least one result row for each row in `host_urls`, even if it has no corresponding rows in `url_status`.

```
SELECT u.*, COUNT(*) AS historySize
FROM host_urls u
LEFT JOIN url_status us
ON us.urlid = u.urlid
WHERE u.publicationid = 1
GROUP BY u.urlid
```

You can replace the `COUNT(*)` with `COUNT(us.urlid)` (or another column from `url_status`) if it's important that `historySize` be zero when there were no matching rows in `url_status`.